# Support library dependencies in Android Q

Tags: android

In order to test my app for Android Q, I've installed Android Studio 3.5 (canary) and updated my build configuration as described here:

https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk

But what do I do with the support library dependencies? The ones below are all red because:

> This support library should not use a different version (28) than the compileSdkVersion (29)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12') {
        transitive = true;
}
```

Do I just leave them as is until Google releases the new support library? I'm getting a build error but I'm not sure if it's related to this or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support libraries will not be updated past 28. You need to migrate to androidx.

See [support library documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library) where it says:

> Note: With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components.
>
> You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*) will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library development will occur in the AndroidX library.